# Fixed thumbnail ratio size & maintaining aspect ratio?

Tags: html, css, thumbnails, aspect-ratio

There are some questions that are properly similar, but i can't relate it to my specific situation.

I have created a responsive thumbnail grid with 4-to-3-to-2 columns structure (in percentages 25%-33,33%-50%).

I'm using a fake placeholder image of 500x330px for testing, but i would like to have a fixed thumbnail placeholder (css code?) with a responsive 500x330 ratio and maintain the aspect radio of the images placed in centered (vertical and horizontal) the placeholder thumbnail.

In the fiddle example i've made some thumbnails in photoshop that have a 500x330px size and within different portrait and landscape sizes so it isn't really a portrait of landscape image, but it gives a idea what i want to achieve. I hope someone understands my question and can help me out or guide me through.

[--> Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/foroloca/zexkuvh9/4/)

```
<div class="col-4">
    <a class="thumb" href="#">
        <img src="img/test2.jpg">
        <div class="caption">Project untitled<br> Category</div>
    </a>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: I am sorry, but what exactly is the question? I might have missed something but it seems to me that your fiddle is exactly what you want?

Comment: Yes sorry my english is not that good properly, but the fiddle shows the portrait and landscape that aren't real, because it is a 500x330px image. I would like to crop a portrait of 250x330px for example and place it in the thumbnail placeholder and it is centered and maintain it's ratio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [This](https://jsfiddle.net/zexkuvh9/7/) is the result you are trying to acheive.

I added a div.img-wrapper around each thumb  and some css magic

## HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="col-4">
        <div class="img-wrapper">   <a class="thumb" href="#">
            <img src="http://mintywhite.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/fond-ecran-wallpaper-image-arriere-plan-hd-29-HD.jpg">
            <div class="caption">Project untitled<br> Category</div>
        </a>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <div class="img-wrapper">   <a class="thumb" href="#">
            <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/500x330/ccc/">
            <div class="caption">Project untitled<br> Category</div>
        </a>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <div class="img-wrapper">   <a class="thumb" href="#">
            <img src="http://www.gettyimages.com/CMS/Pages/ImageCollection/StaticContent/image1_%20164248809.jpg">
            <div class="caption">Project untitled<br> Category</div>
        </a>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <div class="img-wrapper">   <a class="thumb" href="#">
            <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/500x330/ccc/">
            <div class="caption">Project untitled<br> Category</div>
        </a>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <div class="img-wrapper">   <a class="thumb" href="#">
            <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/500x330/ccc/">
            <div class="caption">Project untitled<br> Category</div>
        </a>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-4">
    <div class="img-wrapper">   <a class="thumb" href="#">
            <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f5/Poster-sized_portrait_of_Barack_Obama.jpg">
            <div class="caption">Project untitled<br> Category</div>
        </a>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-4">
    <div class="img-wrapper">   <a class="thumb" href="#">
            <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/500x330/ccc/">
            <div class="caption">Project untitled<br> Category</div>
        </a>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-4">
    <div class="img-wrapper">   <a class="thumb" href="#">
            <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/500x330/ccc/">
            <div class="caption">Project untitled<br> Category</div>
        </a>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

## Changed CSS#

```
.col-4 {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}

.col-4:after {
    padding-top: 63%;
    display: block;
    content:'';
}
.img-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    /*fill parent*/
}
.img-wrapper .thumb {
    height:100%;

.img-project img, .thumb img {
    position:relative;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    -moz-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    -ms-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    -o-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

## FULL CSS

```
/************************************************
Site Name: 
Author: 
************************************************/
 html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    font-family: regular, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.4;
    text-transform: none;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    color: #111;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
body, input, textarea, select, button {
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
:hover {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
b, strong {
    font-weight: normal;
}
a, a:visited {
    color: #111;
    text-decoration: underline;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
h1, nav {
    font-size: 27px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    background-color: transparent;
}
h1 {
    margin: 0 0 26px 0;
}
p {
    margin: 0 0 16px 0;
    background-color: transparent;
}
p a:hover, a:focus, a:active {
    color: #111;
    text-decoration: none;
}
h1 a, a:visited {
    color: #111;
    text-decoration: none;
}
h1 a:hover, a:focus, a:active {
    color: #111;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
/************************************************
Thumbnails - Columns - Content
************************************************/
 #container {
    display: block;
    margin: 98px 10px 100px 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: transparent;
}
.col-4 {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}
.col-4 {
    width: 25%;
}
.col-4:after {
    padding-top: 63%;
    display: block;
    content:'';
}
.img-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    /*fill parent*/
}
.img-wrapper .thumb {
    height:100%;
}
.img-project, .thumb {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
}
.img-project img, .thumb img {
    position:relative;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    -moz-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    -ms-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    -o-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
.thumb:hover img {
    opacity: 0.2;
}
.caption {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 80%;
    padding: 0;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: transparent;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
.col-4 a:hover .caption {
    opacity: 1;
}
/************************************************
Media queries
************************************************/
 @media all and (max-width: 1024px) {
    h1, nav {
        font-size: 22px;
    }
    #container {
        margin: 89px 7px 100px 7px;
    }
    .img-project, .thumb {
        padding: 7px;
    }
}
@media all and (min-width: 769px) {
    nav ul {
        display: block !important;
    }
}
@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
    body {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    .col-4 {
        width: 33.33333%;
    }
}
@media all and (max-width: 479px) {
    .col-4 {
        width: 50%;
    }
}
```

## UPDATE 1

I may have calculated the aspect ratio as 1: 0.63 a bit wrong. You should play with the `padding-top` of the `:after` element to achieve the needed ratio

## UPDATE 2

As you asked added the padding - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zexkuvh9/8/)
I just removed it from `.thumb` class and added it to `.img-wrapper` class.

Comment: Thanks mate! don't really understand how this works, but is it possible to add the padding under each thumbnail it ignores the 10px padding that i had on .thumb class. Edges seems to be a bit blurry now.

Comment: Thank you mate! Great help. It is more code than i thought and the image edges are a bit blurry, but i think i can use it!